# Using python and Tabula to read a data table with string and int

Tags: python, pdf, tabula

I have a very basic pdf file which only contains a spreadsheet with columns and data. code works fine until the spreadsheet contains both numbers and strings.

example below of error:

```
Game                 Unnamed:0          Rating        Players
Final Fantasy VII    nan                Teen          1
Ganbare Goemon       nan                Everyone      2
nan                  13                 Mature        1
```

How can I use tabula to read columns as strings, fixing the problem of tabula splitting columns with both numbers and strings into 2 seperate columns?

code:

```
pdf_files = 'mypdf.pdf'
df_list = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_files, pages='all',guess = False)

data_sheets = pd.DataFrame()
for idx, data in enumerate(df_list):
        if idx == 0:
            data_sheets = data_sheets.append(data)
            headers = data.columns
        else:
            data = data.T.reset_index().T.reset_index(drop=True)  
            data.columns = headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabula doesn't try to detect data types. Inaccuracies in layout detection are not caused by data types.

You can try specifying the horizontal coordinates of the column boundaries. This parameter is exposed in `tabula-py` in the `columns=` keyword argument of the `read_pdf` method.